# Performing arithmetic operations on two inputs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add two numbers that a user enters, and returning the sum, difference, product or the quotient of two values the user enters. For that, I made two inputs with a drop-down list between that. The drop down list has options to add, subtract, multiply and divide. What I am trying to do is perform the operation the user attempts to perform. You can see a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v56fkaww/5/).

```js
//Variables
let firstNum = document.getElementById("num1");
let secondNum = document.getElementById("num2");
let result = document.getElementById("result");

//Event Listeners
firstNum.addEventListener("input", mainFunction());
secondNum.addEventListener("input", mainFunction());
result.addEventListener("input", mainFunction());

//Main JavaScript
function mainFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("options").options[0]) {
    var one = parseFloat(firstNum.value) || 0;
    var two = parseFloat(secondNum.value) || 0;
    result.innerHTML = one+two;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<form>
  <input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="First Number"/>
  <select id="options">
    <option id="addition">&#43;</option>
    <option id="subtraction">&#8722;</option>
    <option id="multiplication">&#10006;</option>
    <option id="division">&#247;</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" id="num2" placeholder="Second Number"/>
  <p id="result"></p>
</form>
```

Please inform me if you find any errors.
Thanks.

Comment: `Please inform me if you find any errors` - You are suppose to tell us if you have any issues or errors. What's your problem and question?

Comment: You will call the javascript function on button click or other event to get calculation of result

Comment: Does it work like you'd expect it to? If yes, no need for this post. If not, tell us what doesn't go right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not A/B testers

Comment: why dont you trigger the event, button click or input change /

Comment: `result.addEventListener("input", mainFunction());` must be `result.addEventListener("input", mainFunction);` as you wanna pass a reference to the function, not its result.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code, the new version is here http://jsfiddle.net/v56fkaww/6/

The error was that you should encapsulate the call of function into an anonymous function

```
//Event Listeners
firstNum.addEventListener("input",function(){mainFunction()});
secondNum.addEventListener("input",function(){mainFunction()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be fine *except* for a small problem :

```
firstNum.addEventListener("input", mainFunction());
```

should be :

```
firstNum.addEventListener("input", mainFunction);
```

Since the function is already defined and this expects a function so you only need to pass a reference to the function.

## Code :

I added functionality for all four operators and shortened the code a bit

```js
//Variables
let firstNum = document.getElementById("num1"),
    secondNum = document.getElementById("num2"),
     result = document.getElementById("result");

//Event Listeners
firstNum.addEventListener("input", mainFunction);
secondNum.addEventListener("input", mainFunction);
result.addEventListener("input", mainFunction);

//Main JavaScript
function mainFunction() {
    var one = +firstNum.value||0;  // convert to number
    var two = +secondNum.value||0; // convert to number
    var opt = document.getElementById("options");
    // this is the shorter than what you are using 
    result.innerHTML = opt.options[0] ? one + two : opt.options[1] ? one - two : opt.options[2] ? one * two : one / two;
    
    
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<form>
  <input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="First Number"/>
  <select id="options">
    <option id="addition">&#43;</option>
    <option id="subtraction">&#8722;</option>
    <option id="multiplication">&#10006;</option>
    <option id="division">&#247;</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" id="num2" placeholder="Second Number"/>
  <p id="result"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: @Luca : oops. my bad

Answer (score 0):

There is also a non standard way to evaluate operator without the need of performing a `switch` or `if` , this is using a Function constructor and execute inmediate. `result.innerHTML = (new Function("return "+one+operator+two))();`

```
//Variables
let firstNum = document.getElementById("num1");
let secondNum = document.getElementById("num2");
let result = document.getElementById("result");
let operator = document.getElementById("options").value;

//Event Listeners
//You should asign the function itself not the result like mainFunction()
firstNum.addEventListener("input", mainFunction); 
secondNum.addEventListener("input", mainFunction);
result.addEventListener("input", mainFunction);
//All of this is like something.addEventListener("input", function(){//code});

function mainFunction() {
    var one = parseFloat(firstNum.value) || 0;
    var two = parseFloat(secondNum.value) || 0;
   //evaluate the operator as a javascipt operator not just as string 
    result.innerHTML = (new Function("return "+one+operator+two))();
}
```

Comment: alternately you could use `eval` for the same effect

Comment: Yes , exactly like that

Answer (score 0):

```
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control text-center tot" id="input1"></td>
            <td id="mark" class="text-center"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control text-center tot" id="input2"></td>
            <td id="total" class="text-center"></td>

function inputOper(operaterName) {
let input1 = Number($('#input1').val());
let input2 = Number($('#input2').val());
let result = $('#total');

if(operaterName == 'add'){
    result = input1 + input2;
    $('#mark').html('+');
}else if(operaterName == 'sub'){
    result = input1 - input2;
    $('#mark').html('-');
}else if(operaterName == 'mul'){
    result = input1 * input2;
    $('#mark').html('*');
}else if(operaterName == 'div'){
    result = (input1 / input2).toFixed(2);
    $('#mark').html('/');
}
$('#total').html(result)
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).